# looking for help with convergence in measure problem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Why is it true that if $(X, \mu)$ is a finite space, $f_n \to f$ in measure, and for each $n$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\mu(E) < \delta \Longrightarrow \int_E |f_n| \leq \epsilon$, then $f \in L^1(\mu)$?

I tried doing something like $$ \int \left| f \right| \leq \int \left| f-f_n \right| + \int \left| f_n \right|.$$  And I can make $\int |f_n - f|$ small except on a small set.  But I don't know how to control $f$ on a small set.

Comment: I think your trying to prove Vitali's convergence theorem. However, I think you need the extra assumption $|f(x)|<\infty$ almost everywhere.

Comment: I was a little confused with the phrasing of the problem, to be honest.  I thought the following was ambiguous: "Assume that $f_n$ satisfies the following property:  For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\mu(E) < \delta \Longrightarrow \int_E |f_n| \leq \epsilon$.  Then $f$ is integrable and $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$."  So you're saying that the test writer meant for the same $\delta$ to apply for all $n$ (uniform integrability) and that an assumption was left out?  Is it possible that the convergence in measure subsumes the hypothesis that $|f(x)| < \infty$ a.e.?